# Some confusions on a basic CMOS multivibrator question

Tags: capacitor, cmos, multivibrator, time-constant

This is a previous exam question, so I do have a solution already, I am not trying to make you solve my homework etc.

---

[image]

Few questions in my mind regarding this question above,

1. There is not a given information about initial capacitor voltage, so I assume it should be understood from the given informatin as "assume the MV is in steady-state for t<0". **But I could not be sure how to relate capacitor voltage to steady state.** Will I replace it with open circuit and then say that V2 has to be @ 9V so that the KCL satisfied at that node, then the gate on the right will outputs 0V, then the left one output 10V. Is this the approach I should follow?
2. Right after the trigger pulse applied, node V1 jumps to 0V, which results node V2 to jump -1V becuause the voltage across a capacitor cannot change instantaneously, right? If so, after this step, I am really having a hard time on how to find the curve for capacitor voltage, initially, it looks like node V2 is qt -1V, so there should be currents flowing towards node V2 both from ground and Vdd, however, this behaviour should change when V2 reaches 0V, after that, the only charging path will(should) be `Vdd & R1`. So the computations for the time it takes for V2 to reach 5V looks pretty complicated to me. However, in the solution of the question, it is taken such that the capacitor will charge up to 9V from -1V with a time constant of (R1//R2). **This doesn't seem correct to me. How does it sound to you?**

Thanks in advance.

update : While -1<=V2<=0 , there is a current flow from GND to V2 and to + terminal of the capacitor. However, once V2 reaches and passes 0V, now there should be the reverse, a current flow from V2 towards GND. This blows my mind.

Comment: For the right-most NOR gate, behaviour changes when its input voltage rises to \$ V_{DD}/2 \$

Comment: @glen_geek yes, I thought I made it clear that I am aware of that part of the question when I typed the following sentence "So the computations for the time it takes for V2 to reach **5V** looks pretty complicated to me"

Comment: Not complicated. It is an exponential rise starting @ -1V....toward +9V. How long does it take to rise to +5V? You have the **R** of the **RC** time constant correct.

Comment: @glen_geek do you mean R1//R2 is correct for time constant? That is the reason I asked the question. I could not understand how R1//R2 can be assumed to be the time constant during the whole process of the charging? If you read my second item again, you can see that why I think it is complicated and don't understand R1//R2 thing.

Comment: Combine R1 & R2 to its Thevenin equivalent. You're right, it is a *little bit* more complex, because charging current also flows through the left-most NOR gate's output, which is a small resistance usually less than 1k. Since it is not specified, assume the NOR gate's output resistance is zero ohms. Also assumed: right-most NOR gate has infinite input resistance and zero input capacitance.

Comment: @glen_geek nope, I cannot do thevenin transformation correctly, tried few times. Maybe you can provide a detailed answer on how to obtain R1//R2 as the eqv. R for time constant, if you have spare time. Either way, thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes u r right completely.
2. your first sentence is right. so what to do next...

The simplest way is to find an equivalent circuit that represents the Vdd, R1 and R2 circuit. It's so simple, in equivalent circuit we have a voltage source of 9 volt (because of resistor division), a equivalent R of 0.9K (1K parallel with 10K), a cap with an initial value. So, we have 3 components: a 9v voltage source in series with a 0.9K resistor and in series with a cap. The cap's initial value is -1v, its final value is 9v and its time-constant (RC) value is (cap*0.9Kohm). So, place them in the exponential charging equation of capacitor and calculate the time when the cap's voltage reaches 5v.

Note that the sentence "this behaviour should change when Vc reaches 0V" is totally wrong here because your circuit (in charging mode) is a pure linear circuit!!!

Generally, we can calculate the equivalent circuit like this: calculate two parameters V_open_circuit and I_short_circuit. Voc in this circuit is 9v (Vdd * R2/(R1+R2)). Isc = Vdd/R1. so the equivalent resistor would be Voc/Isc = 0.9K  and the equivalent voltage source is Voc itself.

Let's evaluate and calculate my equivalent circuit with the real one. At (Vc = -1) the current into cap is (11v/1K + 1v/9K) which is equal to the equivalent circuit (10v/0.9K). At Vc=0 the current of cap is (Vdd/R1 + 0/R2) which is equivalent to (9v/0.9K)

Comment: I mistakenly wrote it as "Vc reaches to 0V", however, I wanted to mean "V2 reaches to 0V", corrected now. How this is wrong? While -1<=V2<=0 , there is a current flow from GND to V2 and to + terminal of the capacitor. However, once V2 reaches and passes 0V,  now there should be the reverse, a current flow from V2 towards GND. This blows my mind.

Comment: u r right in a sense but drawing a wrong conclusion!. In a linear circuits there's is a change in values and not in behavior!. Let's evaluate and calculate my equivalent circuit with the real one. At (Vc = -1) the current into cap is (11v/1K  + 1v/9K) which is equal to the equivalent circuit (10v/0.9K). At Vc=0 the current of cap is (Vdd/R1 + 0/R2) which is equivalent to (9v/0.9K)

Comment: wow! that example is just awesome. You should also include it to your answer for future references, thanks a lot. And preferably, a demonstration on calculating Vth and Rth shortly, would make this answer a bit better.

Comment: you're welcome.